# How do I control a set of tick boxes?

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably simple math but i'm having a bit of trouble with the tick system recognizing positive numbers and applying the ticks properly.

everything is done from a button that controls every item and corresponding tick.
let's say i have 90x pins in stock. someone asks for 130. even though the 130 can't be fullfilled, it should be ticked anyway because 90 pins can still be sent. 
however, if the stock is at 0, no matter how much anyone asks for it can never be ticked. if the stock is also actually higher than what is asked it should then be ticked aswell.

```
If Range("h3").Value >= 0 Then
   Range("bk3").Value = "True"
```

the bk3 is hidden ,its a box connected to the tick.
h3 and its value of 0 is looking for the difference between what is asked and what is in stock.
it could probably be improved to avoid errors.

what happens is even things that are completely out of stock still get ticked, and things that should be ticked,aren't.

Comment: I believe that ticks only work for 1 = Checked, 0 = Unchecked

Comment: Don't use `"True"` as a string use a real boolean `Range("bk3").Value = True`

Comment: `Range("bk3").Value =Range("h3").Value = 0 `  Why not just have the formula in BK3 `H3=0` ?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i've tried it and the same error continues. i've realised it's always the same boxes that get ticked or don't get ticked for some reason,no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

The tick boxes were linked to their respective lines and they were mixed up. that's what was causing the issue.

thanks to everyone for the help anyway